# How can I deny or block an IP Address in Cisco FTD

Tags: cisco, cisco-firepower

I have a Cisco Firepower Threat Defense firewall. I want to Block an IP and add blocked ip into BlockedIp rule.
How can I achieve it via Web Interface or REST API ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using FMC (FirePOWER Management Center) to manage the appliance?

Comment: @JesseP. I am using: Firepower Device Manager